# Sinatra app not deploying to Heroku, rackup crashed

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

**config.ru**

```
require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'heroku'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'thin'
```

**Procfile**

```
web: bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT
```

Here are my heroku logs

```
2013-08-10T01:21:03.753984+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-08-10T01:21:03.754180+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
2013-08-10T01:21:03.754180+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:141:in `start'
2013-08-10T01:21:03.754180+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2013-08-10T01:21:04.799863+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-08-10T01:21:04.790161+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-08-10T01:21:25.615653+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=beer-voter.herokuapp.com fwd="98.173.1.66" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-10T01:22:57.223684+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=beer-voter.herokuapp.com fwd="98.173.1.66" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-10T01:24:34.417907+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2013-08-10T01:24:39.051510+00:00 heroku[run.1200]: Awaiting client
2013-08-10T01:24:39.073013+00:00 heroku[run.1200]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-08-10T01:24:41.746057+00:00 heroku[run.1200]: State changed from starting to up
2013-08-10T01:24:46.002914+00:00 heroku[run.1200]: Process exited with status 1
2013-08-10T01:24:46.018585+00:00 heroku[run.1200]: State changed from up to complete
2013-08-10T01:26:31.150052+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=beer-voter.herokuapp.com fwd="98.173.1.66" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-10T01:29:07.598813+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-08-10T01:29:11.616194+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 26270`
2013-08-10T01:29:15.827320+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config.ru:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./app (LoadError)
2013-08-10T01:29:15.827320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:1:in `block in <main>'
2013-08-10T01:29:15.827320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2013-08-10T01:29:15.827320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-08-10T01:29:15.827320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-08-10T01:29:15.827320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-08-10T01:29:15.827320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2013-08-10T01:29:15.827320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2013-08-10T01:29:15.827320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2013-08-10T01:29:15.827320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2013-08-10T01:29:15.827512+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2013-08-10T01:29:15.827512+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2013-08-10T01:29:15.827512+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
2013-08-10T01:29:15.827512+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:141:in `start'
2013-08-10T01:29:15.827512+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
2013-08-10T01:29:15.827512+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-10T01:29:15.827799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
2013-08-10T01:29:17.475127+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-08-10T01:29:17.455240+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-08-10T01:39:12.643653+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-08-10T01:39:15.630798+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 26323`
2013-08-10T01:39:17.108286+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:1:in `block in <main>'
2013-08-10T01:39:17.108286+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2013-08-10T01:39:17.108286+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2013-08-10T01:39:17.108286+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-08-10T01:39:17.108286+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-08-10T01:39:17.108286+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config.ru:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./app (LoadError)
2013-08-10T01:39:17.108286+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2013-08-10T01:39:17.108286+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2013-08-10T01:39:17.108286+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-08-10T01:39:17.108286+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2013-08-10T01:39:17.108500+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2013-08-10T01:39:17.108500+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2013-08-10T01:39:17.108500+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
2013-08-10T01:39:17.108500+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:141:in `start'
2013-08-10T01:39:17.108500+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-10T01:39:17.108500+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
2013-08-10T01:39:17.108500+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
2013-08-10T01:39:18.608414+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-08-10T01:39:18.624453+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-08-10T01:49:20.129509+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-08-10T01:49:25.310821+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 31607`
2013-08-10T01:49:29.293008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:1:in `block in <main>'
2013-08-10T01:49:29.293008+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config.ru:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./app (LoadError)
2013-08-10T01:49:29.293008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2013-08-10T01:49:29.293008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2013-08-10T01:49:29.293008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-08-10T01:49:29.293008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-08-10T01:49:29.293225+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2013-08-10T01:49:29.293008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2013-08-10T01:49:29.293008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2013-08-10T01:49:29.293008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2013-08-10T01:49:29.293225+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2013-08-10T01:49:29.293225+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-10T01:49:29.293225+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:141:in `start'
2013-08-10T01:49:29.293225+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
2013-08-10T01:49:29.293008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-08-10T01:49:29.293225+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
2013-08-10T01:49:29.293225+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
2013-08-10T01:49:30.776901+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-08-10T01:49:30.787136+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-08-10T01:59:30.949128+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-08-10T01:59:34.018512+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 53386`
2013-08-10T01:59:35.253202+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config.ru:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./app (LoadError)
2013-08-10T01:59:35.253202+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:1:in `block in <main>'
2013-08-10T01:59:35.253202+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2013-08-10T01:59:35.253202+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2013-08-10T01:59:35.253202+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-08-10T01:59:35.253202+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-08-10T01:59:35.253202+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2013-08-10T01:59:35.253202+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2013-08-10T01:59:35.253202+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-08-10T01:59:35.253202+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2013-08-10T01:59:35.253385+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2013-08-10T01:59:35.253385+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
2013-08-10T01:59:35.253385+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:141:in `start'
2013-08-10T01:59:35.253385+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-10T01:59:35.253385+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
2013-08-10T01:59:35.253385+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
2013-08-10T01:59:36.518901+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-08-10T01:59:36.501648+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-08-10T01:59:35.253385+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2013-08-10T02:00:18.345271+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=beer-voter.herokuapp.com fwd="98.173.1.66" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-10T02:02:01.913591+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=beer-voter.herokuapp.com fwd="98.173.1.66" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

And yes, this app is working locally

[image: beer voter running locally]

When I ran `heroku ps` I get this error

```
=== web (1X): `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT`
web.1: crashed 2013/08/09 19:10:11 (~ 8m ago)
```

Comment: Crazy question; but are you working on separate branches; from the logs, it's looking for something that doesn't exist on a *line* that doesn't exist.

Comment: @jackyalcine that is actually not crazy at all. I think something went wrong earlier. I had initialized git for github on a different project on a folder for sinatra practice apps. Then I created this folder for this specific app, then did git init for heroku, not sure if I am explaining that right. I did git remote -v and got this heroku git@heroku.com:beer-voter.git (fetch)
heroku git@heroku.com:beer-voter.git (push)
origin https://github.com/JGallardo/sinatra-ad-server.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/JGallardo/sinatra-ad-server.git (push) . so i removed the origin, still not working.

Comment: By doing `git init`; you added the remote or ran `heroku create`?

It looks like you did the latter using `heroku create`. If so, then that's where the remote got added. Also, from my experiences; Heroku only deploys changes found on the `master` branch.

Comment: @jackyalcine I first created the app on heroku, then later after I created this app, I then added the heroku app as the remote with heroku git:remote -a beer-voter

Comment: With Heroku, it’s a good idea to sync your logs otherwise the outut lines can be mixed up, making backtraces hard to follow. Add `$stdout.sync = true` to the top of your `config.ru`.

Comment: Your answer belongs in the answer, not in the question. Otherwise you don't have a question at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two lines seem to be indicating the problem:

```
2013-08-10T01:29:15.827320+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config.ru:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./app (LoadError)
2013-08-10T01:29:15.827320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:1:in `block in <main>'
```

The app is trying to load your `app.rb` file, but it isn’t there. The fact that your app is working locally suggests that this file hasn’t been added to git. Add this file (and any others your app uses), commit, and then push again:

```
$ git add app.rb
$ git commit
$ git push heroku master
```

Comment: Nice catch, I had put together bits and pieces from stackoverflow and disregarded the file naming. My file was originally named beer-voter.rb, I then modified the config.ru according to a different question when I had a different error. By simply renaming that file, I was able to launch the app successfully. Can be seen at http://beer-voter.herokuapp.com/