# Sinatra app crashes without error on Heroku but works fine locally via foreman - tips?

Tags: ruby, heroku, oauth, sinatra

I have a simple Sinatra app that is working fine locally with Foreman. But on Heroku it crashes instantly:

```
2013-09-17T18:52:37.449716+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=rfcstd.herokuapp.com fwd="38.122.223.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-17T18:55:29.671059+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=rfcstd.herokuapp.com fwd="38.122.223.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

There is no further information about the error.

My app is based on https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/ruby. I have been trying multiple iterations of Procfile and config.ru to get it to work, e.g.

```
Procfile.rb >
web: bundle exec ruby signing.rb -p $PORT

Answer:
Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 14469`
configuration /app/config.ru not found
```

There was no config.ru included in the app so then I tried creating that myself:

```
Procfile.rb >
web: bundle exec rackup ./config.ru -p $PORT
OR
web: bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT

Config.ru >
require './signin.rb'
run Sinatra::Application

Answer:
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=rfcstd.herokuapp.com fwd="38.122.223.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

The Google-coded signin.rb starts up Sinatra, which I think is not a standard way of launching it as a rack app. It seems that Heroku detects the rack app but then chokes on some files not being available... Here is a snippet of signin.rb for good measure:

```
##
# The Google+ Ruby Quickstart lets you get started with the Google+ platform
# in a few minutes.
#
# The app demonstrates:
#  * Using the Google+ Sign-In button to get an OAuth 2.0 refresh token.
#  * Exchanging the refresh token for an access token.
#  * Making Google+ API requests with the access token, including getting a
#    list of people that the user has circled.
#  * Disconnecting the app from the user's Google account and revoking tokens.
#
# Author: class@google.com (Gus Class)
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'base64'
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'sinatra'
require 'google/api_client'
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'
require 'open-uri'
use Rack::Session::Pool, :expire_after => 86400 # 1 day

# Configuration
# See the README.md for getting the OAuth 2.0 client ID and
# client secret.

# Configuration that you probably don't have to change
APPLICATION_NAME = 'MyAppName'
PLUS_LOGIN_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
#set :port, 5000

# Build the global client
$credentials = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load
$authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
    :authorization_uri => $credentials.authorization_uri,
    :token_credential_uri => $credentials.token_credential_uri,
    :client_id => $credentials.client_id,
    :client_secret => $credentials.client_secret,
    :redirect_uri => $credentials.redirect_uris.first,
    :scope => PLUS_LOGIN_SCOPE)
$client = Google::APIClient.new(:application_name => APPLICATION_NAME, :application_version => '0.1')
```

Comment: maybe you do not have all gems installed?

Comment: @akonsu I tested with bundle exec locally and I have all the gems I need in the Gemfile. Also, I think Heroku would complain about a Gem it cannot find. The weird thing is that there is no error notice.

Comment: Yay I found the answer in the comments <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157885/sinatra-app-not-deploying-to-heroku-rackup-crashed?rq=1>: I was working from a different branch locally, that didn't push its changes to Heroku. Heroku only pushes the master branch. Ouch! Working now :)